# Rotation of water inside closed solid sphere

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics

Is there any way to determine the volume of a sphere of water contained inside a solid spherical shell(of known thickness but unknown radius) by studying the rotation of the whole sphere(solid shell and water sphere)? The solid shell is filled with water and has no air or vacancy inside. (We don't know the volume of the sphere otherwise, we would know volume directly). Is a solution possible if the solid shell has water inside but is partially filled i.e. solid spherical shell filled with air and water?

Comment: I don't think i get it, in the first case you have a solid shell of radius say $R$ and inside it a smaller sphere with radius $r$ completely filled with water? Or you have a sphere of radius $R$ filled with water?

Comment: Yes, first one is right, we have a solid spherical shell(with known thickness but unknown radius) and it is filled with water. In the second case, the same shell is filled partially with water.

Comment: How can you know the thickness of the shell but not know its radius? The other way around would make sense...

Answer (score 1):

My qualitative solution to the problem is to consider some kind of motor that rotates the outer shell, outputting a power $P$. A first approximation is to consider a small power. In this way, the external shell is so slowly moving that you may consider all the water at each moment moving with the same angular speed $\omega$ of the outer shell. Since drag cannot be neglected, otherwise the sphere will continue accelerating indefintely, we will consider it from the beginning.

The equation of motion of the sphere is
$$
I\dot{\omega}=T_\text{motor}-T_\text{drag}
$$
where $I$ is the $I_\text{shell}+I_\text{water}$. Considering for simplicity only air drag in the form $T_\text{drag}=\eta\omega$, multiplying by $\omega$ gives
$$
I\omega\dot\omega=P-\eta\omega^2
$$
that has solution
$$
\omega^2(t)=\frac P\eta\left(1-\exp\left(\frac{2\eta t}{I}\right)\right).
$$

Measuring how much time the sphere takes to reach terminal velocity will give information on $I$ and thus on the radius of the sphere. If the sphere is not full you can also deduce the height of the water inside with this method.

The problem with this answer is that it assumes as mentioned that the water is constantly moving at the same speed as the outer shell, which could be a very poor approximation.